# Getting the index of the JSON array using SQL in Snowflake

Tags: sql, arrays, json, indexing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm flattening a JSON data in snowflake using the Lateral Flatten.

I have the JSON data as follows:

```
{
   "Fruits": [
    {
      "Apple_Type" : Type_A,
      "Banana_Type": Type_B
    },
    {
      "Apple_Type" : Type_A2,
      "Banana_Type": Type_B3
    }
  ]
}
```

I used the following query to get the flattened data

```
SELECT  v.value:Apple_Type,
        v.value:Banana_Type
FROM Table1, LATERAL FLATTEN(input => Fruits) v
```

My Result:

```
--------------------------------
| Apple_Type    |  Banana_Type |
--------------------------------
| Type_A        |    Type_B   |
| Type_A2       |    Type_B3   |
--------------------------------
```

How do I get the index of the data. I want the table as follows

```
----------------------------------------------
| Apple_Type    |  Banana_Type |    Index    |
----------------------------------------------
| Type_A        |    Type_B   |      0      | -> Because Apple_Type is from index 0 in the Fruit Array
| Type_A2       |    Type_B3   |      1      | -> Because Banana_Type is from index 1 in the Fruit Array
----------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`INDEX`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html):

> INDEX
>
> The index of the element, if it is an array; otherwise NULL.

```
SELECT  v.value:Apple_Type,
        v.value:Banana_Type,
        v.index
FROM Table1, LATERAL FLATTEN(input => Fruits) v
```

Comment: Thank you, I have been searching for this on many websites but couldn't find it. Thanks, for our help

Comment: Just complementing Lukasz answer that index order is not guaranteed, so be very careful not to use python like PK or FK in future accesses: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten#output